# UWP service to app call

Tags: service, uwp

I have UWP app service with TimeTrigger. Every time this trigger fires i'm trying to download some data from the internet. 
Is there anyway my service can notify my second UWP UI app about data load success|fail? The only way i've found is to run the second service in UI app thread and call it to send the notification.

The original task is to create an always-running data update checking service and load a data consuming UWP UI app that may or may not be running.

Comment: Could you please detail your issue? Are you creating [this AppService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)? Are you having two clients for this service?  Client A for download and client B for notification? How you define the `TimeTrigger`? As I known, app service doesn't have  a TimeTrigger itself.

Comment: I need to write UWP app made of 2 parts. Lets name them as "client" and "service". "Client" is a simple UWP app using data, provided by "service". "Service" is [UWP app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)

Comment: "Service" downloads some often changin data from web and must do his best to keep it as fresh as possible no matter "clietn" is launched or not. The problem is UWP app service wakes up only when client creates connection and disposes when "client" closes. TimeTrigger from "client" disposes too. Overal, i need any mean to keep update check always running

Comment: what you need is first app firing up a `raw` notification and the second app gets triggered when the `raw` notification arrives.